# Traverse a Tree With Oracle. Each Node Has A Property

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hierarchy

I have a simple hierarchy structure in a table (Using Oracle Database 11g)

```
A
|-B
  |-B1
|-C
|-D
```

Each node has a property associated with it (Y or N).

Traversing from the root node (parent), I want to get the first node in each branch that has the property Y.

For example:

```
A
|-B (N)
  |-B1 (Y)
    |--B2 (N)
|-C (Y)
  |-C1 (Y)
    |--C2 (N)
|-D (Y)
```

This should return B1, C and D.

Please give some ideas on how this can be done (code needs to be optimized for time).

Comment: How do you define "first"? You have a parent, say A, with four children A1, A2, A3 and A4. A2 and A3 have the property Y. Which one is **the first one** to have the property? Also in your example, why doesn't A have the property set (to either Y or N)?

Comment: Yes A will also have the property Y/ N. the first one => first node to have Y while traversing from root node

Comment: I understand your first answer (about A also having the Y or N property). I don't understand your second answer. "Traversing from root node" does not give a total ordering on the nodes. I gave you an example: Node A has the property set to N. A has four children, two with the property set to Y. Which of those two children is "the first one" to have the property? "Traversing from root" does not give an ordering of the children; you must provide an additional criterion.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a fancier way than using `sys_connect_by_path`, but I find it very easy to understand.

```
create table hier_test (id varchar2(2), parent_id varchar2(2), prop varchar2(1));

insert into hier_test values ('A', null, 'N');
insert into hier_test values ('B', 'A', 'N');
insert into hier_test values ('C', 'A', 'Y');
insert into hier_test values ('D', 'A', 'Y');
insert into hier_test values ('B1', 'B', 'Y');
insert into hier_test values ('B2', 'B1', 'N');
insert into hier_test values ('C1', 'C', 'Y');
insert into hier_test values ('C2', 'C1', 'N');

select id from (
    select id, prop, sys_connect_by_path(prop, '>') as priors 
    from hier_test
    connect by parent_id = prior id
    start with id = 'A'
    )
where prop = 'Y' and priors not like '%Y>%';
```

Edit: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a9fda/1/0)